# Plotly 3D scatter plot has very small window size in Google Colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, plotly-python

I've got [this .ipynb file](https://github.com/tiago-peres/immersion/blob/master/platforms.ipynb). When opening it it Colab on my Desktop, it works fine

[image: Plotly in Desktop]

If I test to simulate a Galaxy S5 in Chrome the result is also fine

[image: Simulate view]

Yet, I test it in a real mobile phone, the chart appears in such small size that makes it impossible to visualize anything of value there...

[image: Smartphone Colab not looking nice]

How can I make the result in a real mobile phone occupy more space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `update_layout` method on the figure to update the layout.

```
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=0, r=0, b=0, t=0))
```

Just by adding this line, the image would be updated to this.

[image]

You can update other properties as well for example the legend position and their orientation.

```
fig.update_layout(legend=dict(x=.2, y=-1.2),margin=dict(l=0, r=0, b=0, t=0))
```

[image]

This looks good though the size of the 3d image has been reduced.

If we use legend orientation as horizontal then the image is quite good.

```
fig.update_layout(legend_orientation="h",margin=dict(l=0, r=0, b=0, t=0))
```

Thre's no right way to find the exact value of the layout, you need to play with the parameters to get the **approximate** result.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Reached the daily vote limit, will upvote within the next days. Also, not sure why but not able to award the bounty just now. Will do it once I can.